# Clicking some attributedText in a label Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, label, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to make some attributed text clickable in a label.
I added to my view the label and I put auto layout on margins.
Then I added a tapGestureRecognizer to the label, and I connected an @IBAction for it (I also have the outlets for both the label and the gesture).

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer!
@IBAction func tapLabel(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let text = label.text!
    let termsRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms & Conditions")
    let privacyRange = (text as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy")

    if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: label, inRange: termsRange) {
        print("Tapped terms")
    } else if gesture.didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: label, inRange: privacyRange) {
        print("Tapped privacy")
    } else {
        print("Tapped none")
    }
    print("Done")
}
```

Then I added an extension for the gesture recognitionizer

```
extension UITapGestureRecognizer {

    func didTapAttributedTextInLabel(label: UILabel, inRange targetRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
        // Create instances of NSLayoutManager, NSTextContainer and NSTextStorage
        let layoutManager = NSLayoutManager()
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: CGSize.zero)
        let textStorage = NSTextStorage(attributedString: label.attributedText!)

        // Configure layoutManager and textStorage
        layoutManager.addTextContainer(textContainer)
        textStorage.addLayoutManager(layoutManager)

        // Configure textContainer
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0.0
        textContainer.lineBreakMode = label.lineBreakMode
        textContainer.maximumNumberOfLines = label.numberOfLines
        let labelSize = label.bounds.size
        textContainer.size = labelSize

        // Find the tapped character location and compare it to the specified range
        let locationOfTouchInLabel = self.location(in: label)
        let textBoundingBox = layoutManager.usedRect(for: textContainer)

        let textContainerOffset = CGPoint(x: (labelSize.width - textBoundingBox.size.width) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.x, y: (labelSize.height - textBoundingBox.size.height) * 0.5 - textBoundingBox.origin.y)

        let locationOfTouchInTextContainer = CGPoint(x: locationOfTouchInLabel.x - textContainerOffset.x, y: locationOfTouchInLabel.y - textContainerOffset.y)

        let indexOfCharacter = layoutManager.characterIndex(for: locationOfTouchInTextContainer, in: textContainer, fractionOfDistanceBetweenInsertionPoints: nil)

        return NSLocationInRange(indexOfCharacter, targetRange)
    }
}
```

And a function (called in ViewDidLoad)

```
func setupterm(){
    label.text = "By signing up you agree to our \nTerms & Conditions and Privacy Policy"
    let text = (label.text)!
    let underlineAttriString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
    let range1 = (text as NSString).range(of: "Terms & Conditions")
    underlineAttriString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: range1)
    let range2 = (text as NSString).range(of: "Privacy Policy")
    underlineAttriString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue, range: range2)

    label.attributedText = underlineAttriString
}
```

When I run the app on the simulator, the first of the two terms works correctly (if I press "Terms & Conditions" it prints, if I press somewhere else it prints "none"), but the problem is the second one.
In fact, if I press on the "Privacy" text it prints "Privacy", but even if I press under it:
Just to be more clear: if I press under the "privacy" text it doesn't print "none" but it acts like I'm clicking on "privacy"

Comment: add space before privacy as     let privacyRange = (text as NSString).range(of: " Privacy Policy")

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` and use `NSAttributedString.Key.link`?

Comment: Wait... I am using a UITextView. What command are you talking about? How does it work? Is it possible to make two words (which are the same word) both make the app perform the same action? Please post code :3

Comment: @Larme So what do I have to do?